# Is it possible to specify a range of array elements in Python to check against a criteria?

Tags: python, arrays

Hope this isn't a stupid question.
Im trying to avoid typing out a long statement many times.
As the title says, can I check a range of array elements against a criteria in one small statement?

I'm trying to get something like this:
if array[1]...array[4] == 0:
    Something here...

I am aware I can type out 'array[1] =0 and array[2] = 0' etc, but it seems very tedious.

Many thanks!

(I apogize if this post is badly formatted, the mobile interface isn't that great)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in functions with [slice syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

```
if all(i == 0 for i in seq[1:4]):  # for elements with indices between 1 and 4
    pass  # do something

if any(s.startswith('a') for a in str_list[1:2:35]):  # for elements with indices 1, 3, 5 etc. up to 35
    pass  # do something
# etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!

This is the power of loops :

```
for x in range(0, len(array)) :     #loops for each array element
    if array[x] == 0 :              #if any element is == 0 then
        print "hooray!"
```

Don't forget that arrays (or 'lists' in python) are indexed beginning at [0]. The range can also be changed easily if you want to avoid certain sections of the list.

Answer (score 0):

To check if 0:4 elements of array contains zeros, try condition like below:

```
if array[0:4] == [0]*4:
```